# error: 'dvbcsa_u32_aliasing_t' undeclared (first use in this function)?

Tags: c++

I have this patch
https://github.com/fairbird/openpli-dreambox-oe-core/blob/libdvbcsa/meta-openpli/recipes-multimedia/libdvbcsa/libdvbcsa/streamrelay-libdvbcsa.patch

```
--- a/src/dvbcsa_bs_key.c
+++ b/src/dvbcsa_bs_key.c
@@ -63,3 +63,40 @@ dvbcsa_bs_key_set (const dvbcsa_cw_t cw, struct dvbcsa_bs_key_s *key)
     }
 }
 
+void
+dvbcsa_bs_key_set_ecm (const unsigned char ecm, const dvbcsa_cw_t cw, struct dvbcsa_bs_key_s *key)
+{
+  dvbcsa_keys_t kk;
+  int i;
+
+  /* precalculations for stream */
+
+  uint64_t ck = dvbcsa_load_le64(cw);
+
+  for (i = 0; i < DVBCSA_CWBITS_SIZE; i++)
+    key->stream[i] = (ck >> (i^4)) & 1 ? BS_VAL8(ff) : BS_VAL8(00);
+
+  /* precalculations for block */
+
+  dvbcsa_key_schedule_block_ecm(ecm, cw, kk);
+
+  for (i = 0; i < DVBCSA_KEYSBUFF_SIZE; i++)
+    {
+#if BS_BATCH_SIZE == 32
+      *(dvbcsa_u32_aliasing_t *)(key->block + i) = kk[i] * 0x01010101;
+
+#elif BS_BATCH_SIZE == 64
+      *(dvbcsa_u64_aliasing_t *)(key->block + i) = kk[i] * 0x0101010101010101ULL;
+
+#elif BS_BATCH_SIZE > 64 && BS_BATCH_SIZE % 64 == 0
+      uint64_t v = kk[i] * 0x0101010101010101ULL;
+      int j;
+
+      for (j = 0; j < BS_BATCH_BYTES / 8; j++)
+        *((dvbcsa_u64_aliasing_t *)(key->block + i) + j) = v;
+#else
+# error
+#endif
+    }
+}
+
```

And I need to add it to  this file to compile libdvbcsa by bitbake.
https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libdvbcsa/-/blob/master/src/dvbcsa_bs_key.c?ref_type=heads

But I have got this error

```
| ../../git/src/dvbcsa_bs_key.c: In function 'dvbcsa_bs_key_set_ecm':
| ../../git/src/dvbcsa_bs_key.c:86:9: error: 'dvbcsa_u32_aliasing_t' undeclared (first use in this function)
|    86 |       *(dvbcsa_u32_aliasing_t *)(key->block + i) = kk[i] * 0x01010101;
|       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| ../../git/src/dvbcsa_bs_key.c:86:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
| ../../git/src/dvbcsa_bs_key.c:86:32: error: expected expression before ')' token
|    86 |       *(dvbcsa_u32_aliasing_t *)(key->block + i) = kk[i] * 0x01010101;
|       |                                ^
```

Any idea to solve that error ?!!

Comment: Surprised the compiler got past all those `+`s... But seriously grep the source and include folders looking for `dvbcsa_u32_aliasing_t` and see what you find. If it doesn't answer outright, it'll help you write a better question that's more likely to get answered.

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libdvbcsa/ is extremely old. You attempt to apply the patch for the 6 years newer fork https://github.com/glenvt18/libdvbcsa